# Angular-oauth2-oidc adds parameters to redirect uri

Tags: angular, angular-oauth2-oidc

I have issue with the `iss` and also `client_id` query parameters in the redirect uri which are added in it. We are using code flow with PKCE.

The URL looks something like this:

`http://localhost:4200/?iss=https...&client_id=546`

The redirect uri is configured like this:

`redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/'`

Is it supposed to add those parameters to the redirect uri or should they be removed? Is there any option to make it remove them like the `code` and `state`?

`angular-oauth2-oidc: 14.0.1`

`angular 16.2.11`

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  If I follow, you want to implement PKCE but you also want to remove `code` and `state` from the initial call to get a token?

Comment: No, I get the token correctly but when it's redirecting me to the desired url it adds also the `iss` and the `client_id` as parameters like in the example I gave initially.